# Are nested enumerables bad practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, view, enumeration

In my view I'm generating a a number of restaurant menus that are divided into menu categories and within those categories are dishes. Right now I have my template setup as so:

```
<% @menus.each do |menu| %>
  <h2><%= menu.name %></h2>
  ...    
  <% menu.categories.each do |category| %>
    <h3><%= category.name %></h3>
    ...
    <% category.dishes.each do |dish| %>
     <p><%= dish.name %></p>
      ...
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I was wondering what would be best practice when it comes to nesting multiple enumerables in this fashion? Aside from inserting this code into a partial, is there a better way to accomplish this without cluttering the view. Is it fine as is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the way your models are setup (`Menu` *has_many* `categories`, `Category` *has_many* `dishes` etc.), if you are to show all those information in the same view, you have no other way rather than just looping through them and show the required data in your view which is fine, IMHO. I don't see any problem with that.

Just one tip, while looping through the associated model's data, you just need to be careful that you always have the data present for the associated model attributes, otherwise you may get `undefined method 'method_name' for nil:NilClass` error for some of them. To avoid that problem, you can also use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try). e.g.

```
menu.try(:name)
category.try(:name)
dish.try(:name)
```

etc.

That way, your view will not explode if some or any one of the associated model has no data present (i.e. `nil`).

Comment: Thanks. As far as `menu.try(:name)` would you still advise using this if the attribute(s) already has a validation in place?

Comment: validations are definitely better. Using `try` is a not-so-good idea. If you can make sure your nested resources are always present using validation, then that's the best thing to do :)

Comment: Good to know. Thanks again.